# Populate Email Body from Lightning component using Lightning for Gmail

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I am using Lightning for Gmail extension provided by salesforce. Just developed a **custom component** for it, now i want to populate **gmail compose email body** as it is done through Email Template component. Is there any api or interface in lightning for it. So far i already implemented **clients:availableForMailAppAppPage,clients:hasItemContext** interfaces to get people,messagebody etc. just want to set message body now.

Answer (score 0):

I see that we cant edit outlook fields (to,cc, subject, body) from component and it is still in salesforce roadmap.
Let me know if you found a workaround