# Can a Custom Component Populate Gmail Subject and Body Fields Using the Lightning for Gmail Application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email-template, lightning-for-gmail

All that the documentation says is the following:

> ```
> The subject indicates the subject on the current email. <aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" />
> The messageBody indicates the email message on the current email. <aura:attribute name="messageBody" type="String" />
> ```

I assumed that I could write to thse fields because the Lightning for Gmail Application itself can write to the Gmail body and subject fields using the template component. However, when I try to set the aforementioned attributes, I can only register the changes in my custom component; the Gmail fields in the email composition modal stubbornly remain unchanged. Does anyone have a definitive answer or another way to write to the Gmail body and subject fields using the a custom component in the Lightning for Gmail application? Thanks in advance.

(same question was asked over a year ago [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193011/populate-email-body-from-lightning-component-using-lightning-for-gmail) and received no responses)

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from Salesforce. The subject and body fields in the Gmail composition window are not writable using a custom component in the Lightning for Gmail Application at this time.[image]